# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Currently, we have a strong user base with a very high number of Stack Exchange moderators. However this site is not intended just for covering moderation issues relating to the Stack Exchange network. How can we find and attract moderators, community managers and interested parties from other corners of the web, and how can we make them feel valued in what is currently a site with an overwhelming SE bias?

Comment: some advice from the SO blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be tricky in many instances. Particularly because trying to advertise / promote a site is going to border on spam in many instances.

One *possible* route to take is that many sites with moderation have a 'contact the mods' option. (Either PM'ing them or other more global methods) so *perhaps* - and I would suggest only doing so if you're a frequent user of such sites - is you could use that option to contact site mods to suggest they visit.

I am not a moderator on any site other than SE though, so I'm not sure how I'd feel about being directly contacted in such a way regardless of how useful it is. I've no idea how much spam comes direct to moderators in such a manner anyway, so it could just get dismissed and / or risk you getting suspended from such sites. So YMMV, as they say.

Answer (score 0):

We could definitely leverage SE's search engine presence as a sort of "self-advertising". By asking really good questions that a lot of moderators have, we can attract people who are doing their own research on how to deal with tricky issues.